# kendo custom Validation not fired with razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I can't understand why the email validation message (alert('a')) only get called when I don't use the kendo MVC helper, => the html output looks identical.

***What I'm missing ?***

How it should work:
http://dojo.telerik.com/OSIpa/2

I created an Edit-Template with this content:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
.Value(Model)
.AddAttribute("type", "email")
.AddAttribute("placeholder", "example@orphy.com")
.AddAttribute("pattern", Share.Validator.MailValidator.REGEX_MAIL_PATTERN)
.Name(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName))

<input type="email" class="k-textbox" value="@Model" placeholder="example@orphy.com" id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" patern="@Share.Validator.MailValidator.REGEX_MAIL_PATTERN" />
```

Usage:

```
<form id="myform">
     @Html.EditorFor(r=>r.WebSite, "EmailTemplate");
    <button>Validate</button>
</form>

 $(function () {
            var validator = $("form").kendoValidator({messages: {
      email: function(input) {
              alert('a');
            }

            }}).data("kendoValidator");

            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (validator.validate()) {
                    alert("ok");
                } else {
                    alert("oopps");
                }
            });
        });
```

The Output:

```
<input class="k-textbox k-valid" id="WebSite" name="WebSite" pattern="^[^@]+@[^@]+$" placeholder="example@orphy.com" type="email">
<input type="email" class="k-textbox k-valid" placeholder="example@orphy.com" id="WebSite" name="WebSite" patern="^[^@]+@[^@]+$">
```

Comment: look a you are not using correct kendo widget configuration refer to this telerik documentation and demo   http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/validation      and http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/validation

Comment: what's incorrect ?